# Python curses - getting error texts in nice way

Tags: python, error-handling, ncurses

I am developing ncurses app in python. But everytime, when my second thread (or anything else) throw exception, or print som text, it mess my window.

Is there any option, how to catch this text and handle it properly, without ruining my awesome ncurses program design? :)

Thank you

Comment: When you say "how do I catch this", do you know about [try/catch](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) blocks?

Comment: Yeah, of course, but I have 2 classes, both are running together in 2 threads. One class is doing ncurses stuff and second is about connection, etc... But if that second write some error, which occours in some extern library, that error is written accros my ncurses screen.

Comment: So why not catch the exception which is causing the write error so you don't get the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, `catch` all appropriate exceptions at the entry to your threads' call stacks.  In all likelyhood, the slave threads should catch it in order to relay the exception (via [`Queue`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes), e.g.) to the display, or perhaps a log.

Alternatively, you can suppress the printout of the default exception handler (though your question focuses on this aspect, it's almost certainly not what you want):

```
import sys

sys.stdout.close()
sys.stderr.close()
```